# Is it normal for two compute intensive tasks to slow down each other even if they have a lot of cores to run on?

Tags: performance, mpi

I am running a compute intensive program(VASP) on my workstation which has

```
Cpu: 64
Thread per core: 2
Cores per socket: 16
Sockets: 2
NUMA node: 2
```

When I use the command `mpirun -np 8 executable` it finishes fast, but when I use the same command twice simultaneously. Both processes slow down significantly even though they have a enough number of processors to work independently of each other. Is something wrong with my MPI installation?

I want to be able to run multiple jobs of this kind simultaneously, but cannot find a way to launch them as independently as possible. So that the performance doesn't take a hit. Apart from assigning more than 64 cores, what would be my limit for running tasks parallelly?

*I checked slurm but i t seems to be designed to handle nodes and such things, will it of any advantage on my workstation?*

Comment: The limit is *heat*.  That first run started off on nicely cool processor chips, they got hot and slowed down the second run.

Comment: AFAIK MPI runtimes tends to bind threads (and so indirectly MPI processes) to core. Thus, if you run 2 MPI program simultaneously, then the threads will compete for the same resources. This is a big issue for performance. You should try to control the thread binding (there are usually environment variables and launch parameters for that). Some MPI runtime can print the affinity so you can see if such issue happens. Alternatively you can check the number of core actually used by 1 and 2 programs using basic tools like `top` and `htop`.

Comment: Shared resources can also often slow down programs running simultaneously. IO devices are often a bottleneck (but not so much in HPC applications which are designed not to do many IOs because it is expensive). The DRAM is also a frequent source of bottleneck, especially in HPC applications. Even the L3 cache can be an issue in some cases. MPI collectives ran by MPI programs in a shared-memory machine tend to be generally memory-bound. This is dependent of the target application and target usage. IDK for VASP.

Comment: Try disabling process binding done by MPI, if you use Open MPI, you can `mpirun --bind-to none ...` (note the default is to bind a MPI task to a socket, so it might have little effect). You will also need to disable OpenMP binding if applicable. You are more likely sharing the memory bandwidth and this is what is affecting the performances. you can `for pid in $(pidof executable); do grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/$pid/status; done` to check the MPI binding.